# Does Git support more than 32 chars in filename in windows?

Tags: msysgit

We have a problem in cloning a repository created in unix in to a Windows box.

Git fails while checking out a lengthy file that has more than 32 characters in windows.

The file name is given below.
BaseFCS_x0020_OnLine_x0020_Identicheck_x0020_verification_x0020_serviceConsumer.java*

Is there a way to fix this issue in Git?

Answer (score 0):

Try the version from cygwin (not msys).

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be an issue with the windows not supporting more than 260 characters. Informed the team to rename the file and directories.

Answer (score 0):

This should also run with msys. 
Just try to clone it to a shorter path like C:\Dev or so.